Buffered HTTP streaming server sends previous frame instead of current frame
I'm developing an HTTP streaming server in Python that serves MJPEG frames. The server is supposed to stream frames from a buffer to connected clients. However, I noticed that the displayed frame is always the previous one, not the current one. This problem occurs on my windows and linux machine.
Here is an example to reproduce the problem:
import io
import threading
from functools import partial
import socketserver
from http import server
from threading import Condition

class StreamBuffer(io.BufferedIOBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, data):
        with self.condition:
            self.frame = data
            self.condition.notify_all()

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, stream_buf, *args, **kwargs):
        self._stream_buf = stream_buf   
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/stream.mjpg')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', "0")
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                with self._stream_buf.condition:
                    while True:
                        self._stream_buf.condition.wait()
                        frame = self._stream_buf.frame
                        if frame is None:
                            continue
                        self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                        self.send_header('Content-Length', str(len(frame)))
                        self.end_headers()
                        self.wfile.flush()
                        self.wfile.write(frame)
                        self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
                        self.wfile.flush()
                        self.log_message("Sent frame")
            except Exception as e:
                self.log_message('Removed streaming client %s: %s', self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

def start_streaming_server(host, port):
    buf = StreamBuffer()
    handler = partial(StreamingHandler, buf)
    server = StreamingServer((host, port), handler)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever, daemon=True, name="StreamingServerThread")
    server_thread.start()
    return buf, server, server_thread

In the python console run:
from stream import start_streaming_server
buf, server, thread = start_streaming_server("localhost", 8000)
img = open("/path/to/some/image.jpg", "rb").read()
buf.write(img)   # nothing happens
buf.write(img)   # now the first frame is displayed

